# Geometry Nodes: join two circles to create a cylinder

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes, solidify-modifier

I'm trying to create a procedural mesh using Geometry Nodes.

For example, in this screenshot, I'm joining two Mesh Circles as if to make a Cylinder.
[image: Mesh Circles]

Can I connect the two with geometry somehow? If not using this method, I'd be very grateful to learn however it is possible. I tried with the Solidify and Skin Modifiers, but didn't get anywhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is also possible to create mesh with a *Convex Hull* Node. But this method is only to apply for a convex shape.

For details, please see following figure:
[image: Add a Convex Hull node after the Join Geometry node.]

Answer (score 2):

I found this method with the Curve to Mesh node:
[image: Procedural Cylinder]

Answer (score 1):

Since Blender 3.1, you can just create one Circle and use the *Extrude Mesh* Node:

[image]